# How to update already installed software via command line?

Tags: command-line, updates

I'm looking for a command line to update my already installed software.I want to update all of them.

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: You may also use `aptdcon --refresh` followed by `aptdcon --safe-upgrade`. This has the advantage of not requiring sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal(Ctrl + Alt+ T) and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```